# Snowflake transformation while copying data from external stage to snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to multiply accountid column with 10 while loading data from the external stage to the snowflake table.

Below is the query used in snowflake:

```
copy into account(accountid, accounttype)
   from (select to_number(t.$1,10,1)*10, t.$4 from @azure_ext_stg/snowflake/account.csv t)
   file_format = my_csv_format
   FORCE = TRUE;
```

Above results in the below error when executed in Snowflake.
002300 (0A000): SQL Compilation error: Function '*' not supported within a COPY

Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. COPY Transformation doesn't support arithmetic operations.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#supported-functions

If this is blocking your business, please submit a ticket to Snowflake Support. They may provide a workaround.

Comment: Appreciate your response! So, for this kind of transformation (arithmetic), we have to use other tools/software maybe ADF before dumping data into Snowflake tables.

Comment: Yes, you can use other tools to preprocess or after ingesting, you can do these calculations. You may also create a view or virtual column for calculations.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gokhan Atil pointed out, COPY doesn't handle any processing logic.

You could dump the pre-processed data into a raw table and then run a stored procedure that contains the processing logic and an insert statement which dumps the data into the target table.